# "errorMessage": "Decimal('1') is not JSON serializable"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

```
import boto3
import json
import os

s3 =  boto3.client('s3')
ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddb.Table('test_table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   response = table.scan()
   body = json.dumps(response['Items'])
   response = s3.put_object(Bucket='s3-testing',
   Key = 's3-testing.json' ,
   Body=body,
   ContentType='application/json')
```

[lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRFL4.png)

Hi guys I am trying to run this code but I keep receiving this TypeError: Decimal('1') is not JSON serializable. When I play around and import Decimal, it gives me this "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"

I am assuming I have to add simplejson but do not know how to go around it.

[execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INghf.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Paste the code into your question instead. Also, what is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to get past this error message